SEO efficient 301 redirects (non-https to https, non-www to www) in 1 hop
Performing an audit of my site revealed multiple 301 redirects to achieve a HTTPS, www. variant, with a trailing slash of all directories.
Ideally I'd like to make only one 301 redirect from any url variation, to https://www.example.com/page/
A lot of the answers I've found online will have multiple hops, or not clear up a lack of trailing slashes on directories...etc.
Currently I'm using:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

to redirect http traffic in my vHost config to HTTPS variant. However:

HTTPS non-www URLs are still valid
HTTPS URLs without a trailing slash are still valid

Is it possible to incorporate HTTPS Non-www URLs and non-trailing slash URLs in the above so I can 301 to the correct destination in one hop?

One hop isn't needed.  Search engines can all deal with short redirect chains.  If you have redirect chains of more than five URLs, you probably want to reduce that, but a couple redirects for the purposes you describe are fine.

Hi @StephenOstermiller, small world!! I'm trying to reduce the hops to 1 as I have multiple sites that could benefit from this - purely from an SEO perspective. However I do take your point.

it goes something like this:
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS and non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Add trailing slash if missing (only for directories)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

Don't forget to clean up the comments in the code I left for you)
You can check redirects quickly, for example with - https://www.redirect-checker.org/

Here’s a refined .htaccess configuration to ensure a single 301 redirect to enforce HTTPS, www, and trailing slashes for directories:
RewriteEngine On

Redirect HTTP to HTTPS and non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Add trailing slash for directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

This handles HTTP to HTTPS, non-www to www, and trailing slashes in one step, avoiding redirect chains that can hurt SEO.
Replace example.com with your domain name.
On another note, I recently started using Cloudways, and their built-in tools for redirect management have been a time-saver. For example, you can handle HTTPS redirections at the server level without needing to edit .htaccess manually, which simplifies tasks like this. I got it a 40% discount for Black Friday, not sure if the offer is still up. Something worth checking out.
